# How can I share an audio from whatsapp to my android app?

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

I'm trying looking for resources to know how to share audio from WhatsApp to my app, but I can't find any. I only have found how to share from app to WhatsApp but not from WhatsApp do an android app. If you know some resource that may help me, I will be very happy with it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a intent filter for your problem such as a one below,

```
<intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        <data android:scheme="file"/>  
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>  
</intent-filter>
```

I think the action needs to be changed.

An intent filter must be defined in the Manifest.xml file

After declaring the intent-filter your Manifest.xml will look like this,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
    </intent-filter>  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        <data android:scheme="file"/>  
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>  
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Comment: This doesn't work...the app doesn't appear in the list when sharing.